# EXCEL VBA VLOOKUP when the source is QUERY TABLE (or ListObject)

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I'm stuck, I used to run a code that perform a vlookup from a query (data from web power query) - see example in the code below).
It all ran smooth, until i tried to add more queries, and then I needed to change the function to perform the vlookup from varies queries, and for that I needed the queryName to be a var. no matter what I try, it doesn't work for me (**replacing the "US" in the vlookup**):

```
Function doVlookup(selectedSheet As String)

Dim queryName As ListObject
Set queryName = Worksheets("US API").ListObjects(1)

Debug.Print queryName.Name

Sheets(selectedSheet).Select
Range("A1").Select

Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(VLOOKUP(RC1,US,5,0)<>0, VLOOKUP(RC1,US,5,0),""-"")"
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.FillDown
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A1").Select
End Function
```

the var queryName, does have the desired table, but when I run the code it just return #NAME! for all keywords.
If I hard code it back to "US" (in the example, it is hard-coded) it runs without a problem.
I tried:

- queryName
- Range(queryName)
- queryName.Range
- queryName!R1:R100
- queryName.Range.Select
- queryName.DataBodyRange

For clarification "queryName" suppose to replace the "US" in the following: `"=IF(VLOOKUP(RC1,US,5,0)<>0, VLOOKUP(RC1,US,5,0),""-"")"` Just that I am not sure how it's done. "US" is a name of a table that is loaded from a connection of "data from web" to the sheet "US API".

any idea what should bet put in the place of the hard-coded US to make it work?

Comment: Can you select the query range and name it, then use it in your formula ?

Comment: What does `queryName` has to do with the rest of the code you displayed here?

Comment: It suppose to replace the "US" in the following: "=IF(VLOOKUP(RC1,US,5,0)<>0, VLOOKUP(RC1,US,5,0),""-"")"
Just that I am not sure how it's done. "US" is a name of a table that is loaded from a connection of "data from web" to the sheet "US API".

Comment: How about writing "US" or other to a cell and then referencing that cell in the formula?

Comment: Doesn't work.
US - in this case, is a placeholder for a table's name.
This code: "Worksheets("US API").ListObjects(1)", does get me the table, and by adding ".Name" to it, I thought I'll be able to refer to it as well, but something is off, and it just returns #NAME...
So, it's either I need to refer to this query with a different Data type or, I need to find a way to write this code in a different Way...

Answer (score 0):

I realize it's a month after the fact, and you've likely moved on to bigger and better things, but I think I may know how to tackle this.  Here is an example of a dumbed-down spreadsheet and the VBA code that will implement a vlookup on various listobjects.

[image]

In this example, I use the corresponding table values from the first, second and third tables (listobjects) in each of the lookups for G7-9, just to show how each can be declared dynamically.

```
Dim lo As ListObjects
Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects

Range("G7").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1]," & lo(1).Name & "[#All],2,FALSE)"
Range("G8").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1]," & lo(2).Name & "[#All],2,FALSE)"
Range("G9").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1]," & lo(3).Name & "[#All],2,FALSE)"
```

I suspect the missing link in your code above is the `[]` following the listobject name, which indicates the range within the table to use.